# Reading numeric terminal input into an array and sorting the array [Bash]

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, sorting, user-input

I've been trying to read numeric input from the terminal in Bash (Two separate approaches. First is directly entering numbers into the CLI and second reading the numbers from a file) and saving it in an array, sorting the array and showing the result. (The original problem stated that the input is saved in an array and then sorted)

I don't know if it's better to save it in a file and sort the values in the file or directly the input from the terminal into the array and sorting it afterwards. I have searched for both methods.

Thank you.

P.S. I've read many sources and links but unfortunately I couldn't come across a solution. I've tried using loops and prompting the user in asking how many numbers they want to feed in as the input but it was doomed to failure.

Answer (score 1):

Where does the input come from? Someone entering numbers, or a file, another process?

Either way, you seem to expect a finite number of inputs which then need sorting. Just pipe your inputs into `sort -n` (`-n` is for numeric sort). No need to use an intermediate array.

```
# Print some numbers on the console, pipe into sort.
cat <<-EOF | sort -n
1
3
2
EOF
```

If your inputs are coming from a file:

```sh
# Create FILE holding unsorted numbers.
$ cat <<-EOF > FILE 
1
3
2
EOF

# Sort contents of FILE.
$ cat FILE | sort -n
1
2
3
```

If you could be more specific, it would be easier to help.

Comment: You are right. I'll edit the question. There wasn't really a strict recommendation in how to approach this problem. But I tried both ways. Reading from user input within the terminal itself and reading from a file and sorting the values inside.

Answer (score 1):

Would you try the following:

```
if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    # This line is executed when input from the terminal.
    echo "Input a numeric value and enter then continue. Enter a blank line when done."
fi

while read -r n; do
    [[ -z $n ]] && break    # exits the loop if the input is empty
    ary+=("$n")
done

sorted=($(sort -n < <(printf "%s\n" "${ary[@]}")))
printf "%s\n" "${sorted[@]}"
```

- It accepts both user's input from the terminal and redirection from a file.
- It expects the input to be a list of values separated by newlines.
- When typing on the terminal, a user can complete the input by entering
  a blank line or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
- The array `ary` holds the values in the input order.
- The array `sorted` holds the sorted result.
- The script does not check the validity of the input values. It may be
  better to examine if the input is a valid numeric value depending on the application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What an elegant and nice solution! Thank you